# NextJs activate DatadogRum depending of env

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js, environment, datadog

We currently have multiple environments and we would like to init datadogRum only for production.

In the _app.tsx I tried something like this :

```
import { datadogRum } from '@datadog/browser-rum';

if (process.env.NODE_ENV=== 'production') {
  datadogRum.init({...});
  datadogRum.startSessionReplayRecording();
}
```

But this is not working because env variables are not available here ...

Do you have any work around for this ?

Comment: You have to persist your session to the client/page. There are a variety of ways https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/overview

Comment: @bwest Thx for your quick answer. But I init datadogRum in the _app.tsx but ouside of my App component.
Should I init it inside my component ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I succeed using @bwest comment.

I used nextJs `getInitialProps` in order to transmit my env variable.

And I put my datadog init code in a `useEffect(() => {...} , [])` hook to only execute the code once.

Answer (score 0):

With nextjs environment variables can be available to front-end code.

They will be interpolated inside your code using some webpack plugin (something like EnvironmentPlugin or DefinePlugin).

From this [Nextjs documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables):

> Next.js comes with built-in support for environment variables, which allows you to do the following:
>
> - Use .env.local to load environment variables
> - Expose environment variables to the browser by prefixing with NEXT_PUBLIC_