# How to get environment variables on client side with Next.js?

Tags: typescript, next.js, environment-variables, datadog

I want to read environment variable into Next.js, how to pass data into `datadogRum.init`?

```
// _app.tsx

import React from "react";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import type { AppProps } from "next/app";
import { datadogRum } from "@datadog/browser-rum";

export default function App({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  useEffect(() => {
    datadogRum.init({
      applicationId: applicationID, // can't use process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_DATADOG_APPLICATION_ID directly here
      ...
    });

    datadogRum.startSessionReplayRecording();
  });

  return (
    ...
  );
}

App.getInitialProps = async () => {
  return {
    applicationID: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_DATADOG_APPLICATION_ID,
  };
};
```

This way can't get the `applicationID` value.

Comment: Why can't you use `process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_DATADOG_APPLICATION_ID` inside the `useEffect`?

Comment: @juliomalves `pageProps.applicationID` got `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'applicationID')`. Use process.env.xxx directly got `Type ‘string | undefined’ is not assignable to type ‘string’. Type ‘undefined’ is not assignable to type ‘string’.`

Comment: Default it to a string value to satisfy the type constraint, e.g. `datadogRum.init({ applicationId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_DATADOG_APPLICATION_ID ?? '' });`. Or better yet, make sure `process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_DATADOG_APPLICATION_ID` is a string before calling `datadogRum.init`.

Comment: @juliomalves Thank you! It works! Just in another question, I found it needs to transmit env data: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72365875/nextjs-activate-datadogrum-depending-of-env

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to pass the environment variable from `getInitialProps`. You can access it directly inside the `useEffect`, you just need to make sure `process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_DATADOG_APPLICATION_ID` is defined before initialising `datadogRum.init` to avoid typings conflicts.

```js
export default function App({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
    useEffect(() => {
        if (typeof process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_DATADOG_APPLICATION_ID !== "undefined")
            datadogRum.init({
                applicationId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_DATADOG_APPLICATION_ID
                ...
            });

            datadogRum.startSessionReplayRecording();
        }
    });

    return (
        ...
    );
}
```